# How to set environment variable using Gradle?

Tags: gradle, build, environment-variables

I know I can't set environment variable directly from Gradle, but is there some other solution?. I need to do this:

- do some stuff..
- set 4 environment variables (their values depend on some settings)
- run some ant scripts (that depend on environment variables)

I thought of creating a file (`.setenvironment`) with all the settings I need, and then source it from Gradle (`source .setenvironment`), but I fear that I wouldn't be able to reset the variables if something goes wrong (and I need to set "JAVA_HOME", for instance, which is also important for the build scripts themself).

Answer (score 0):

You can't set environment variables from java and other JVM languages. The only way of doing it is via [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

You can also set the variables before gradle is run.

Comment: Can't I add Exec task that should fire "bash -c source .setenvironment" (so, .setenvironment would contain presets for these variables)?

Comment: Yes you can, however I'm not sure if these settings will be available on other gradle tasks.

Comment: @zorglub76, if my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it.